# Scrolling the listview changes the position of headers

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, simplecursoradapter

I have a `Sectioned ListView` in which the headers like **"A"** , **"B"** ,...**"Z"** are are showing at prpoer position when i first loads the app and scroll down the list. But whenever I scroll-up (back to top) the `List`, then the positions of header are changed and sometimes overlaping to other catagories.

My customr `Adapter` is :

```
private class MySimpleCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

        Holder holder = null;
        public MySimpleCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor cur,
                String[] from, int[] to, int flag) {
            super(context, layout, cur, from, to, flag);
        }

        public String getTitle(String contName) {
            return contName.substring(0, 1);
        }

        @Override
        public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor mCursor) {

            holder =new Holder();
            final int curPosition  = mCursor.getPosition();
            String cont_Name = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));

            holder.titleText= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.section_title);
            holder.contactTitle= (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            holder.contactDetail = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            holder.myImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);  

            Log.d("Cursor Postion " , ""+ curPosition);

            if( curPosition == 0 ){
                    holder.titleText.setText(getTitle(cont_Name));
                    holder.titleText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    keyWord = getTitle(cont_Name);
                }           
            else if (keyWord.equalsIgnoreCase(getTitle(cont_Name))){
                    holder.titleText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    keyWord = getTitle(cont_Name);
                }else if (keyWord != getTitle(cont_Name)){
                    holder.titleText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.titleText.setText(getTitle(cont_Name));
                    keyWord = getTitle(cont_Name);
                }else{
                    holder.titleText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

            holder.contactTitle.setText(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME)));
            holder.contactDetail.setText(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)));
        }
}
```

Whereas, my `layout` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<TextView
android:id="@+id/section_title"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textColor="@android:color/white"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/section_title"
    android:contentDescription="@string/contact_img" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
     android:layout_below="@+id/section_title"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
    android:text="@+id/textView1"
    android:textColor="@color/Black"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:text="@+id/textView2" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: still holding my breath and waiting for help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally Got my answer my own after two weeks...my `if-else` conditions were too complex , so i make comparison on some different criteria.

```
if (mCursor.getPosition() > 0 && mCursor.moveToPrevious()) 
            {
                preName = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                mCursor.moveToNext();
            }
            else if(mCursor.getPosition() == 0)
            {
                preName = null;
            }
            else{
                preName = null;
            }

            if(preName != null){
                preTitle = getTitle(preName);
            }

//===============================================================================
            /*          
             * Setting Header And Contact Details
             */
//===============================================================================

            if(mCursor.isFirst()){
                holder.titleText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.titleText.setText(itemTitle);
            }

            else if(preName != null){

                if(! itemTitle.equalsIgnoreCase(preTitle))
                {
                    holder.titleText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.titleText.setText(itemTitle);
                }else{
                    holder.titleText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }

            holder.contactTitle.setText(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME)));
            holder.contactDetail.setText(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)));
```